# Convexity of the solution of an o.d.e.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis, dynamical-systems, convex-optimization

Are there any results on proving the convexity of a function defined implicitly through an ode?

More specifically I'm interested in proving convexity of a function
$f(t,u):\mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{+}$ in $u$ ($0 \leq u  \leq 1$) for
all $t$ given that it satisfies the following ode:
$$
\frac{\partial f(t,u)}{\partial t}=a-\min(u,f(t,u)),
$$
with initial condition $f(0)$.

---

**Update 2:**
Here is a more basic question (which can help answering the original one): can we show that $f(t,u)$ is nonincreasing in $u$ for all $t$? (without solving the ode) This is very intuitive: one can think of $f$ as the content of a buffer/tank at time $t$ with input rate $a$ and output rate $\min(u,f(t,u))$. The output rate is at most $u$ but also cannot exceed the current content level. By increasing $u$ we are basically increasing the potential output rate and hence it must be that $f$ is nonincreasing in $u$.

---

**Update 1:**
Eventually I'm interested in showing convexity when $a$ is also a function of $t$, i.e., $f$ solves
$$
\frac{\partial f(t,u)}{\partial t}=a(t)-\min(u,f(t,u)).
$$
This is why I'm looking for an implicit approach to prove convexity (rather than solving the ode). 
When $a(t)=a$ the ode can be solved (as @daw mentioned) by considering the two cases $u<f(t,u)$ and $u \geq f(t,u)$. This leads to two ode's with solutions given by
$$
f_{1}(t,u)=f_{1}(s)+(t-s)(\lambda-u),\\
f_{2}(t,u)=(f_{2}(s)-a) \exp(-(t-s))+a,
$$
which characterize the solution of the original ode: Given an initial condition $f(0)$ the solution is given by one of the equations above with the possibility of crossing over to the other equation at most once. Here is a plot of the trajectory of $f$ for a fixed $u$:

[image: Solution of the ode for a given $u$]

As you see given initial condition $f(0)=1$ the solution is given by the first (linear) equation $f_{1}$ but once it reaches $u=0.9$ it takes the exponential form of $f_{2}$.

The solution is also continuous in $u$ and I'm pretty sure convex in $u$ for all $t$ even when $a=a(t)$. Here is a plot of $f(t,u)$ as a function of $u$ for differnet values of $t$:

[image]

I believe something can be done by differentiating the ode with respect to $u$ and trying to show the monotonicity of the derivative, but I haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: Can you try to study the sign of $${\partial^2 f \over \partial u^2} \leq 0?$$

Comment: I'm interested in convexity in $u$, not $t$. Also $f$ is not twice continuously differentiable in $u$.

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Comment: You can solve the ODE by a case distinction $f<u$ and $f>u$. Then it is a matter of calculus to compute $f$ given initial values $f(0,u)$. This would give $f$, and it be easier to decide convexity.

Comment: That's correct but I'm looking for an implicit argument that doesn't require solving the ode.

Comment: How smooth is $f$?

Comment: @OskarLimka $f$ is continuously differentiable with respect to $u$. Please see the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can construct solutions to your differential equation for which convexity in $u$ does not hold.

Take any continuous function $a(t)$ that satisfies $a(t) \geq 1$ for all $t \geq 0$.   Take any (possibly nonconvex) function $g(u)$ that satisfies $g(u) \geq u$ for all $u \in [0,1]$.  Consider the function: 
$$f(t,u) = g(u) -ut + \int_{0}^t a(\tau)d\tau$$

Claim:  This function $f(t,u)$ satisfies the following for all $t \geq 0$ and all $u \in [0,1]$: 
$$ \frac{\partial f(t,u)}{\partial t} = a(t) - \min[u, f(t,u)] $$

Proof: We first show that $\min[u, f(t,u)]=u$. Fix $t \geq 0, u \in [0,1]$. Then:

\begin{align}
f(t,u) &= g(u) - ut + \int_0^t a(\tau)d\tau \\
&\geq u - t + \int_0^t a(\tau)d\tau \quad \mbox{[since $g(u)\geq u$, and $u \in [0,1], t\geq 0$]} \\
&= u + \int_0^t [a(\tau)-1]d\tau \\
&\geq u \quad \mbox{[since $a(\tau)\geq 1$ for all $\tau \geq 0$]} 
\end{align}

Hence, $\min[u, f(t,u)]=u$ for all $t \geq 0$ and all $u \in [0,1]$.   Hence, for $t \geq 0, u \in [0,1]$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f (t,u)}{\partial t} &=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[ g(u) -ut + \int_{0}^t a(\tau)d\tau \right] \\
 &=-u + a(t) \\
&= a(t) - \min[u, f(t,u)]
\end{align}
$\Box$

Now observe that if our chosen function $g(u)$ is not convex over $u \in [0,1]$, then for any fixed $t\geq 0$ the function $f(t,u)$ defined above is not convex in $u$.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks! Isn't this assuming that the initial condition $f(0,u)=g(u)$ and hence possibly a convex function of $u$? So it wouldn't work for a constant initial condition?

Comment: Yes the initial condition here is $f(0,u)=g(u)$. The wording in your question was unclear when you said "with initial condition $f(0)$" since $f$ is a function of 2 variables.

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. I'll accept your solution. So you think with a constant initial condition it's gonna be convex? Any idea on how to show that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, the above solves your differential equation for the case $a(t)\geq 1$ for all $t$ (more generally, the same solution holds as long as $t \leq \int_0^t a(\tau)d\tau$ for all $t$).  And for $f(0,u)\geq u$ for $u \in [0,1]$. The solution is such that if $f(0,u)$ is convex in $u \in [0,1]$ then $f(t,u)$ remains convex in $u$.

Comment: Right so basically we know it is convex for $a(t)>1$. For a constant initial condition (which is the case I'm interested in) the solution is unique. Do you have any idea about proving convexity for the case with $a(t)<1$? That is the more interesting case...

Comment: When $a(t)>1$ the solution form can change as the trajectory might go below $u$.

Comment: This goes back to the daw comment.  The solution to $\frac{\partial f(t,u)}{\partial t} = a(t) - f(t,u)$ is $$f(t,u) = g(u)e^{-t} + e^{-t}\int_0^t e^{\tau}a(\tau)d\tau$$ and various assumptions on $g(u)$ and $a(t)$ ensure $f(t,u)\leq u$ for all $t \geq 0, u\in [0,1]$.  For example, if $g(u)\leq 0$ and $a(t)\leq 0$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Comment: A thought experiment:  Fix $t\geq 0$. Suppose there are subintervals such that $f(t,u)\geq u$ for $u \in [0, u_1]$, $f(t,u)<u$ for $u\in[u_1, u_2]$, $f(t,u)\geq u$ for $u \in [u_2, u_3]$, and so on. If you splice together convex solutions $f_i(t,u)$ that hold over those subintervals, and if those solutions match function values and derivatives at the endpoints, then the entire function is convex over $u \in [0,1]$.